# Excel: Contents of the last previous non-empty cell in a column (above active cell)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column that can contain any number of blank cells in a row. Whether a cell is blank or not depends in a complex way on the contents of several other columns. If the cell is not blank, it should contain 1 plus the contents of the last previous non-blank cell (i.e the lowest non-blank cell that is above it in the same column). I need to update these numbers dynamically.

How do I find the value of the last previous non-blank cell in a column?

I would prefer to do this by formula, but I am willing to use a VBA approach if there is no workable formula approach.

I would be very grateful for any help I could get.

Comment: A sample would help a lot here

Answer (score 1):

A VBA user-defined function:

```
Function PrevPlus()
    Application.Volatile
    PrevPlus = Application.Caller.End(xlUp).Value + 1
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have numbers in those cells then this formula in A100 would find the previous number in A1:A99

`=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,A1:A99)`